# Pandas dropping columns by index drops all columns with same name

Tags: pandas

Consider following dataframe which has columns with same name (Apparently this does happens, currently I have a dataset like this! :( )

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"a":range(10,15),"b":range(5,10)})
>>> df.rename(columns={"b":"a"},inplace=True)
df

    a   a
0   10  5
1   11  6
2   12  7
3   13  8
4   14  9

>>> df.columns
Index(['a', 'a'], dtype='object')
```

I would expect that when dropping by index , only the column with the respective index would be gone, but apparently this is not the case.

```
>>> df.drop(df.columns[-1],1)

0
1
2
3
4
```

Is there a way to get rid of columns with duplicated column names?

**EDIT: I choose missleading values for the first column, fixed now**

**EDIT2: the expected outcome is**

```
  a
0 10
1 11
2 12 
3 13
4 14
```

Comment: Indeed I passed 1 to drop columns. I also got out empty df (the 01234 is index). I was just expecting I would get rid of the second(last, containg values 5 to 9, hence the -1) column and the dataframe would not become empty, but would have index 0 to 4 and values 0 to 4. Sry for choosing misleading values for the "a" column

Comment: @Pocin "Is there a way to get rid of columns with duplicated column names?" All columns had duplicated names and you got rid of them what else do you want?

Comment: My bad, today is not my day. In the edit I added expected outcome. The confusion springs from the fact that if I would like to get rid of *all* columns with duplicated names i would use `df.drop("a",1)`. I wanted to bypass this by using integer column indices, but it had same effect as `df.drop("a",1)`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Actually just do this:

```
In [183]:
df.ix[:,~df.columns.duplicated()]

Out[183]:
   a
0  0
1  1
2  2
3  3
4  4
```

So this index all rows and then uses the column mask generated from [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.duplicated.html) and invert the mask using `~`

The output from `duplicated`:

```
In [184]:
df.columns.duplicated()

Out[184]:
array([False,  True], dtype=bool)
```

**UPDATE**

As `.ix` is [deprecated](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#whatsnew-0200-api-breaking-deprecate-ix) (since v`0.20.1`) you should do any of the following:

```
df.iloc[:,~df.columns.duplicated()]
```

or

```
df.loc[:,~df.columns.duplicated()]
```

Thanks to @DavideFiocco for alerting me